# Echo store name once with all the categories

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 tables interlinked with each other.

**store_manufacture**  --------------     **Categories** --------------------------         **Store_Categories**

```
-----------------      --------------------          -----------------------
sm_id  | sm_name         cat_id | cat_name            sc_id|store_id|cat_id
-----------------      --------------------          -----------------------
12    | HP                 1    | Travel                1  |  12    |  1
                           2    | Health                2  |  12    |  2
                           3    | Electronics           3  |  12    |  3
```

I want to display storename once with all the category ids which i have to post to the next page.Here is a code i have tried:

**php**

```
 $cat_fetch=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT 
 sm_id,sm_brand_name,cat_id,sm_image,sm_link FROM `store_manufacture` sm 
 INNER JOIN store_category sc ON sc.store_id=sm.sm_id");
 while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($cat_fetch,MYSQLI_ASSOC){
 $id=$row['sm_id'];
 echo " <h5> <a href=''>" .$row['sm_brand_name']."   ". $row['cat_id']."</a></h5>";
 }
```

**Output**

[image]

**Desired Output**

```
HP (Travel, Health,Electronics)
```

Comment: Study up on `GROUP_CONCAT()` and `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"SELECT 
 sm.sm_name,GROUP_CONCAT(c.cat_name)  as cat_name FROM `store_manufacture` sm , Categories c, Store_Categories sc
where sm.sm_id = sc.store_id AND c.cat_id = sc.cat_id GROUP BY sm.sm_id";
```

this is query you should run hope this will help you

Comment: The query works perfect! but how to echo `cat_name` then? It gives an error. `$row['cat_name']` **Error:**  `Undefined index: cat_name`

Comment: `GROUP_CONCAT(c.cat_name) as cat_name` just update the query.

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo Thanks!!